# How to recover space after bulk update in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an index of around 20GB; the documents have several large fields, many of which are now redundant.

So I decided to use bulk update to set those fields to empty, in the expectation of recovering space on the server.

I tested a small number of instances, using code of the form:

```
POST myindex/doc/_bulk
{"update":{"_id":"ccp-23-1002"}}
{"doc" : { "long_text_1":"", "long_text_2":""}}
{"update":{"_id":"ccp-28-1007"}}
{"doc" : { "long_text_1":"", "long_text_2":""}}
```

This worked fine, I did a search, they showed the fields long_text_1 and long_text_2 were now blank on the specified docs, the other fields unchanged.

So then I scripted something to run the above across all the docs in the index, 1000 at a time. After a few had gone through, I checked the data in the console using

```
GET _cat/indices?v&s=store.size&h=index,docs.count,store.size
```

... which showed that while the index in question had the same number of documents, the store.size had got larger, not smaller!

Presumably what is happening is that in each case after an update, a new doc has been created with the same data as the old doc, except with the fields specified in the update request changed; and the old doc is still sitting in the index, presumably marked as dead, but taking up space. So the exercise is having exactly the opposite of the intended effect.

So my question is, how to instruct ES to compact the index or otherwise reclaim this dead space?

Comment: Probably due to refresh interval setting, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-disk-usage.html for some tips on tuning disk usagr

Comment: You can use the force merge API to delete the expired data, ES/Lucene only release space after merge.